# PresentationFontCache using 50% CPU, how to code to prevent this

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've written a XAML/C# program for doing some simple math calculations and displaying the results on the screen.

It uses some story boarding, and simple color changes, which is why I don't understand why `PresentationFontCache` sometimes goes crazy and hogs the CPU.

Is there a way to prevent `PresentationFontCache` from running in code?  I'm only using about 3 different fonts so I don't really need this to run.

A code based solution is needed, since I can't go to every user's machine to disable it via services.

Comment: if your going to down vote at least give a reason ?

Comment: Its Vista/7
Also I noticed that Visual Studio 2010 and ExpressionBlend (Both written in WPF) do not cause presentationFontCache to run...

Comment: I think the problem is independent of the code,

Comment: A quick search gave multiple instances of others with the same issue. Such as http://blog.tune-up.com/myth-buster/the-case-of-the-mysterious-presentation-font-cache-cpu-hog/

Comment: ****A code based solution is needed, since I can't go to every user's machine to disable it via services.****